# How can I pass a php variable to an external php file im getting data from with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have 2 files, index.php and ajax.php, I am retrieving data from ajax.php to display in index.php via ajax.. I would like to pass the username to ajax.php to use in my sql statement.. How can I achieve this?

index.php -

```
$profile_user =$_GET['user'];

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.loader').hide();
        var load = 0;
        var nbr = "<?php echo $nbr;?>";
        $(window).scroll (function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                $('.loader').show();
                load++;
                if(load * 5 > nbr){
                    $('.messages').text("No more to see..");
                    $('.loader').hide();
                }else{

                $.post("ajax.php", {load:load},function(data){
                    $(".images").append(data);
                    $('.loader').hide();
                });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

ajax.php

```
$profile_user =$_GET['user'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE  user = '$profile_user'  ORDER BY ID DESC ";
```

Can I pass the variable in the ajax call?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up JavaScript and PHP here in an impossible way. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript).

Comment: be a lot simpler if you just stored user in session variable instead of passing it all around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the PHP variable in the AJAX call

```
$.post("ajax.php", {
  load: load,
  user: '<?php echo $profile_user; ?>'
},function(data){
```

And change `$_GET` by `$_POST` in your *ajax.php* file, like this

```
$profile_user = $_POST['user'];
```

Comment: Works like a champ Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You need to POST that data:

```
            $.post('ajax.php', {load:load, user: '"<?php echo $_GET['user'];?>"'},function(data){
                $('.images').append(data);
                $('.loader').hide();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
$.post("ajax.php", {load:load},function(data){
                    $(".images").append(data);
                    $('.loader').hide();
                });
```

to

```
$.post("ajax.php", {load:load, user:user},function(data){
                        $(".images").append(data);
                        $('.loader').hide();
                    });
```

And in ajax.php after getting mysql result just encode the array in json format and echo it.

```
$data = mysql_query($sql);
echo json_encode($data);exit;
```